# Division Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Remainder Theorem

> If there exists an integer $a$ and a positive $b$, then there exists a $r$ and $q$ such that
>
> $$a=bq+r , \ \ \ 0 \le r\lt b$$

I wanted to know if my proof is correct for *only* the case that $a$ is negative integer.

*Proof.*

Assume the case of positive $a$ has been proved

Let $a$ be a nonnegative integer so that we get

$$-a = b\cdot q+r$$
$$\Longrightarrow r= -a-b\cdot q$$

Now let $\mathscr S $ be a set as follows:
$$ \mathscr S =\{ -a-bq\ |\ \ q \in \mathbb Z\} $$
and let the set $\mathscr R$ be defined as:

$$\mathscr R =\mathscr S \cap \mathbb Z^-$$
Thus $\mathscr R$ is the set of all negative remainders  and $-a \in \mathscr R$ since $-a = -a - b \cdot 0$ where $(q=o)$. Because $\mathscr R$ is non-empty and contains only negative elements, there exists a greatest integer in  $\mathscr R$. Let this greatest integer be denoted by $-r$.

Now $$-r <0  \Longrightarrow 0<r$$ so we know that $r$ is positive. Now take the next biggest remainder, namely $-r+b$. We know that $-r+b \gt -r$ , thus $-r+b \notin \mathscr R$ and consequently $-r+b \gt 0$. This implies

$$-r<-b \Longrightarrow r\le b$$

Therefore we have proven $r$ and $q$ exist such that $a<0$ and $a=bq+r , \ \ \ 0 \le r\lt b$

***If it is incorrect can you please explain why or give the correct proof. Thank you.***

Comment: Just to be clear - you are assuming the case of positive $a$ to prove the case of negative $a$? If so, you should state that explicitly.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes I am. I'll correct that. But can this proven if I hadn't assumed the case of positive $a$?

Comment: If $a,b$ are integers, $\mathscr S\subseteq \mathbb Z$ so $\mathscr R=\mathscr S$. Did you mean $\mathscr R=\mathscr S\cap\mathbb Z^{\geq 0}$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes thanks again, staring at the computer screen for too long over looked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is correct, however there is a weirdness/incompleteness to it because you never explicitly choose $q$. It follows that $q$ exists, but you never specify how to choose it. Simply saying something like "let $q_0$ be the value of $q$ such that $r=-a-bq$" would suffice.

A side note about theorem phrasing: "if there exists an integer $a$..." sounds weird to me, because *of course* there exist integers. $1$ is an example. It sounds like this proof says "if we assume integers exist, then ..." I think saying one of the following would be better:

- "Let $a$ be a positive integer ..."
- "For $a,b$, $a$ an integer and ..."
- "If $a,b$ are integers with $b$ positive ..."

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I also wanted to ask if this is the best proof or there is some other way to do it that you might know of? Once again thanks.

Comment: Not really, no. This is more or less the same as what I would write. It is worth noting though, that if you have proven the other case, you can use that to prove this case in a few lines by multiplying by $-1$ and then doing some arithmetic.